# How to check if website exist with puppeteer.?

Tags: puppeteer

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
const page = await browser.newPage();              
await page.goto('$url', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});
const cookies = await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies');
```

I want to check the if website is accessible with provided protocol.

If tried to access with `http` and failed, need to check whether its accessible with `https`

Is it possible to do with puppeteer.?

Comment: Do you actually want to check if HTTPS (on port 443) is available or do you simply want to call `page.goto` again with "https" instead of "http"?

Comment: I want to check if https is available then hit https else check if http is available

Answer (score 1):

`puppeteer` will throw an error if it is not able to `page.goto` a page, so I'd suggest catching that error and then correcting the course:

```
try {
    await page.goto('$url', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});    
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
}
```

Comment: `0` disables the timeout ([docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options)). A `timeout` of `0` would not make any sense anyway ;)

Comment: @ThomasDondorf Ouch, indeed it does (a momentary lapse of reason was caused by pptr's immediate failure to open a page with timeout `0` when debugging the answer)

Comment: Probably it's to late, but I would like to link to similar answer which would provide correct location [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26007248/1053480).

Also in my solution I considered just error as 404, in other case if location not provided it considered as `http://some.link.com`. 
Code example: 
`const result = (res && res.headers && res.headers.location) || \`http://${url}\`;`